# Maven - pass argument to use in mvn package

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jira-plugin

I'm new to maven, I want to asign dinamically the jar version of a jira plugin passing a parameter to maven  by command line (win7 with maven 2.1.0), so I can generate the jar file name with the svn revision:

```
mvn -Dsvnrev=1 package
```

or

```
mvn package -Dsvnrev=1
```

but have an error: *[INFO] Invalid task '1': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal*

I define the parameter in pom.xml but, is there something I'm missing?

```
<properties>
    <myprop>MyJarStaticName${svnrev}</myprop>
</properties>

<version>${myprop}</version>
```

also I have tryed

```
<properties>
    <myprop>${myprop}</myprop>
</properties>

<version>MyJarStaticName-${myprop}</version>
```

I had a watch to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421918/maven-pass-argument-to-use-in-exec-maven-plugin/14212756) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757426/maven-specify-the-outputdirectory-only-for-packaging-a-jar) but It doesn't work for me :(

Comment: What are you using such an old Maven version? up-to-date 3.0.4!. The version of an maven artifact can't given dynamically via command line. What you can do is to use buildnumber-maven-plugin to get the information from SVN and put it into the MANIFEST.MF file.

Comment: I use that version because is the version that comes with Jira sdk 3.11, I don't know if it's possible to update maven but works for me at the moment. How does I put the svn revision into Manifest.mf file?, and how does maven takes the info from this file to generate the jar name? I only know a little knowledge of pom or settings structure, but never heard about manifest.mf. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For command

```
mvn -Dsvnrev=1 package
```

Try using

```
${env.svnrev}
```

in pom.xml